# latex thinks reference is undefined

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, multicol

I know that very similar questions have been asked before, but the solutions do not work.
I have the following latex code;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
blahblah in figure\ref{diagram1}.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/diagram.png}
\caption{blahblahblah }
\label{diagram1}
\end{figure}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

and I obtain the following error message;

```
Reference `diagram1' on page 2 undefined
```

No matter how many times I attempt to recompile the document using pdf latex, I obtain the same error.

Has anyone here encountered this before? Where latex is clearly wrong, but you do not comprehend how/why?

Comment: I'm going to guess that latex is not wrong, but without a complete example that reproduces the problem, I can't say any more.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code snippet that you have provided is not enough to trouble shoot your problem.

Comment: there are any number or reasons that might happen. Impossible to tell unless you show a test case a `\nofiles` command for example. Or  `\renewcommand\label[1]{}` or ....

Comment: Ian Thompson: I say that latex is wrong as it states that the reference is undefined when it is.

Andrew: Thank you, I have added the necessary minimal working example.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with multi-column!

Comment: You were right Pouya!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX already told you the reason:

```
Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!.
```

And the entire float object is gone including the `\label`. Therefore the reference is undefined.

Also `H` is not supported causing an error, which is fixed by adding package `float`. If you don't want a floating object, then there are other means to add a caption, see the following example.

Also if there are two columns, then there is no place for an image with width of the whole `\textwidth`. `\linewidth` is better, because it reflects the current line width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
blahblah in figure\ref{diagram1}.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/diagram.png}
  \captionof{figure}{blahblahblah }
  \label{diagram1}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you want to have a figure across the full text width, then `figure*` instead of `figure` can be used, but only as floating object without `H`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
blahblah in figure\ref{diagram1}.

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/diagram.png}
\caption{blahblahblah }
\label{diagram1}
\end{figure*}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't receive the "Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!." warning.

Comment: The first solution does not work, giving the error "
 ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \caption "

However the second works just as you say.

Comment: @PlokavianNerveGas Therefore the first solution is *not* using `\caption{...}` but `\captionof{figure}{...}`, provided by package `caption` or `capt-of`.